Apple Sign In with Rails and Kamal raises ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error
Context: Apple sign-in worked fine until a week ago when the company moved the app to Kamal. We started getting this error:
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (HTTP Origin header (https://appleid.apple.com/) didn’t match request.base_url (https://www.myapp.com/))

I found some suggestions to forward the X-Forwarded-Proto header so I configured it in Kamal but it didn't fix the issue.
I also found a suggestion to set the Origin header to your own domain, but I don't think that's configurable with Kamal.
Any other ideas or help fixing this issue is appreciated.
